# Own users table instead of oauth_clients with OAuth2-server for Lumen

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, lumen, lumen-5.2

I've successfully implemented an OAuth2-server in my Lumen API with this [Tutorial](http://mrgott.com/joomla/24-integrate-oauth2-server-into-lumen-to-secure-your-restful-api-with-access-tokens). The tutorial uses the [OAuth2 server for Laravel + Lumen](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel).

Unfortunately the [documentation part of creating own grants](http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/custom-grants/) isn't there yet.

In my database there is the **oauth_clients** table now. But I have also an own table **users**. There are some more information about user. All entities are referencing to this table.

Now I want to check the **users** table for the credentials ***instead*** of the **oauth_clients** table. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**oauth_clients** table is for managing client_id and client_secret (along with scopes etc) only.

You need to use PasswordGrant instead of ClientCredentialsGrant in order to authenticate users (and thus dealing with **users** table along with **oauth_clients**).

See: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/blob/master/docs/authorization-server/password.md for more details

PS: In Lumen you might get an exception with this:

```
  if (Auth::once($credentials)) {
      return Auth::user()->id;
  }
```

So you'll need to rewrite it in a way similar to this:

```
$user = User::where('username', strtolower($username))->first();

if (!isset($user)) {
    return null;
}

if (app('hash')->check($password, $user->getAuthPassword())) {
    return $user->id;
}

return null;
```

NOTE: You still need oauth_clients table with at least one client_id/client_secret combo defined (notice that secret isn't a hash and is expected to be plain)

After setting it up you'll be getting your access token like (not exactly like this, depends on your implementation):

```
curl -X POST http://yourapp/access_token -d "grant_type=password&client_id=test&client_secret=testsecret&username=testuser&password=testpass"
```